# Script for Deleting old data from sqlite3 databases

Tags: database, bash, sqlite

Currently I'm deleting manually old data (old more than 90 days) from `sqlite` databases, so below are the steps currently following for that. so guys Is that possible to do this job using Bash Script ??

```
1. cd /opt/db                   (my database location)
2. ls -lSh | head -n30          (sorting from top highest size .db files and notes all .db names)

3. sqlite3  test1.db            (select database)
4. delete from tbl_outbox where time<='2016-02-10 00:00:00';      (delete data older more than 90 days)
5. vacuum;
```

there are more than 20 `.db` files. so I do again above one by one steps 3 to 5 like below

```
sqlite3  test2.db

delete from tbl_outbox where time<='2016-02-10 00:00:00'; 
vacuum;
```

can you someone help me to create bash script for do this task.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell can loop ... supposing you use bash or ksh you can use something like the below example:

```
cd /opt/db
DATESTRING=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00" -d "now -90 day")
for DBFILE in *.db
do
  echo "delete from tbl_outbox where time<='$DATESTRING'; vacuum;" | sqlite3 $DBFILE
done
```

If you prefer to have it run on a specific list of databases substitute 
*.db with a space separated list of your db file names ... if it's ok to have this run against /opt/db/*.db it will need no editing if you add/remove a database

Comment: Useless use of ls: I suggest to replace `$(ls *.db)` by `*.db`.

Comment: yes sort of .... it's the whole command substitution that is unnecessary, but in that for you get the idea that you can put any command in there.
I suppose I already showed that in 
DATESTRING=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00" -d "now -90 day")
So I'll etit it and do as you suggest.